# jquery swap image on element click not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap an image on click with jquery. I have got it to work with the click being bound to the image class. However, if I try and wrap the function and bind the event to a button or anchor, it will not swap the images. Here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$(".test_toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
});
</script>
```

This worked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
  } else {
    this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: live has been deprecated and removed. What old version of jQuery are you using? Binding events to anther click is normally a bad idea since clicking it multiple times will add multiple event handlers.

Comment: Try changing `$(this).find` to `$.find`, I think your searching for the images inside your button. Can't verify it, but that's just by looking at your code during commute :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. At present your code says "on click of .test-toggle add an event listener to .img-swap"

Comment: I will change now with your recommendations and will change live() to click as a function and $.find thank you both I will post and update

Comment: can you nest a click within a click? @StanSmulders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to delegate the event listeners so I've removed them. Simply add the click event to the image and then you can manually 'trigger' a click on it when the `.test-toggle` is clicked. E.G:

```js
$(function() {
  
    //add on click event
    $(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if (this.src.indexOf("_off")>0) {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
    });
  
    //add remote trigger
    $(".test_toggle").on('click', function(){
        $(".img-swap").trigger("click");
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img-swap" src="https://placehold.it/300?text=_off" />
<button class="test_toggle">test toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because unlike like `img`.

`a` or `button` doesn't have a `src` attribute.

So when you bind the event to a button or anchor, `this.src` in your second instance of the code will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete this line:

```
 $(this).find(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
```

What is it's purpose? You can swap this image right after the first click, right?
Also, make sure that `.img-swap` is inside the tag with class `test_toggle`.
You are using:

```
$(this).find(".img-swap")
```

`find()` searches only in children of selected element.

If it's not nested use

```
$(".img-swap")
```

instead of:

```
 $(this).find(".img-swap")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written the js, but not tested. Can I nest clicks?

```
$(".test_toggle").click(function(){
    $.find(".img-swap").click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
        this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

Comment: No, you can't - and why would you? The swap should happen on the click. You can do away with the whole 'if' statement. After the click, you search the inages and swap their source :)